# Spotlights not touching the scene

Tags: modeling, lighting, scene

I'm new-ish to Blender, mostly using it on a casual basis. I have no experience with cycles or nodes but am working with basic geometry to make a floor plan/scene in my spare time.

My issue, which I haven't understood the answer to in the questions I looked for, is that the spotlights I've added to the scene aren't even affecting the rendered image. At first it was grey with the world lighting, but after I followed some advice and lowered the world strength it simply went black. My spotlights aren't working at all.

Very basic question but would love some help with this[image]

Comment: Increasing the power to 1000 or 10000 watts usually fixes it. Watt values usually aren't  below 100

Comment: Thank you, that helped me!